# How can i get the file path of the file that's open?

Tags: php, url

I need the file path of the pages in my website.

a normal link is this: http://thecouch.000webhostapp.com/reviews/2017/05/moonlight/index.php

but i need this: reviews/2017/05/moonlight/index.php

Is there a php function that does that? I tried getcwd but it gave me this: : /storage/ssd2/202/1552202/public_html. I'm using 000webhost by the way.

Answer (score 3):

PHP comes with a way to get parts of a URL. For this case you would use the following.

```
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Learn more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use parse_url() to make it. And you can check the **[live demo here](https://eval.in/806419)**.

```
<?php
print_r(parse_url('http://thecouch.000webhostapp.com/reviews/2017/05/moonlight/index.php'));
```

output,

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => thecouch.000webhostapp.com
    [path] => /reviews/2017/05/moonlight/index.php
)
```

added to get path in a variable, you can use **[method of Abraham A.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44222855/6521116)** or below code.

```
$path = parse_url('http://thecouch.000webhostapp.com/reviews/2017/05/moonlight/index.php')['path'];
```

Comment: ok so you get that, and how do you take the [path] to make it into a variable? what is the syntax to do that? is it $path = print_r(....) and then i use $path[path] ?

Comment: @luisalcantara you can access with index. chek my answer. and you can check it [here](https://eval.in/806422)

Comment: ok it works. But when I open another review it gets this file path too, is there a way to do 'this' but like with any file where you get the correct one?